# Accessing member of java pojo set as exchange property in the camel spring route

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I have written my route using spring xml which looks like this

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="classpath:props.properties" />
        <route>
            <from
                uri="activemq:queue:adapter.queue?mapJmsMessage=false&amp;disableReplyTo=true" />
            <log message="This is a status request"></log>
            <process ref="psuedoRoute"></process>
        </route>
</camelContext>
```

As I am getting a Java POJO through my activemq end point, and that is the exchange body. Is it possible to read the value of a string member within this route xml itself?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible. You may use [SPEL](http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/spel.html), it allows to call a method of Java object, getter in your case.

It could be like:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="classpath:props.properties" />
        <route>
            <from
                uri="activemq:queue:adapter.queue?mapJmsMessage=false&amp;disableReplyTo=true" />
            <log message="This is a status request"></log>
            <process ref="psuedoRoute"></process>
            <log message="This is a status request"></log>
            <setBody>
                <spel>#{body.getValue()}</spel>
            </setBody>
        </route>
</camelContext>
```

Comment: You don't need SPEL for that. The Simple language should do the trick as well: `<simple>${body.value}</simple>`